# Sending values as parameters in HTTP GET using VBA request

Tags: vba, excel, http

So I am trying to send a basic request to a new API I'm testing out with the following script:

```
Sub CalcDemo()
    TargetURL = "https://my-api-url.com"
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    postData = "user=myUsername&password=myPassword"
    HTTPReq.send (postData)
    MsgBox (HTTPReq.responseText)
```

End Sub

But I'm getting the following error message: `HTTP Status 401 - user and password should be specified as parameters on the request`.  I was under the impression that the manner in which `postData` is being passed above meant they are sent as parameters, but I guess I am wrong.  How can I send a string of parameters?

Comment: That is not a GET but a POST, so `HTTPReq.Open "POST", TargetURL, False`

Comment: To add - if it were a GET you'd be doing something like: `TargetURL = "https://my-api-url.com?user=myUsername&password=myPassword"` (ie. parameters are passed in the querystring portion of the URL).  In a POST, the parameters are passed in the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one comment has suggested, you are trying to send a post string usin a GET command. If you replace the folowing line, it should work:

```
    HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
```

replaced by:

```
    HTTPReq.Open "POST", TargetURL, False
```

Comment: Looks like this is the right answer.  Interesting because I did the same thing as a GET request in python and it worked, but the POST request gave me this error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the value of postData is not collecting the values of the variables myUsername or myPassword. you have to create the concatenated data like so:

```
postData = "user=" & myUsername & "&password=" & myPassword
```

I suppose that myUsername and myPassword are global variables. Otherwise you also need to pass them as arguments to your function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I tried

`postData = "user=" & "myUsername" & _
        "&password=" & "myPassword" & _
        "&param1=" & "param1val" & _
        "&param2=" & "param2val" & _ `....

But am still getting the same error.  Just by a cursory check, the params look to be formatted properly.

Comment: And yeah, I just changed the username and password to placeholders :)